# Activity has leaked window DecorView while using alertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Everytime i try to show a alert dialog to the user and the user dismisses the dialog using the button inside the alert. I get the following error.

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity SplashActivity has leaked window DecorView@5f814ed[SplashActivity] that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:765)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:440)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:95)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:473)
    at SplashActivity.errorDialogue(SplashActivity.java:363)
    at SplashActivity$2.run(SplashActivity.java:196)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8016)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

The code I have written and tried is below:

```
private AlertDialog errorApiAlertDialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if (getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.POS_CODE)) != null) {
        RestApi restApi = new RestApi(this, context);
restApi.checkPOS(getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.RTR_TOKEN_ID)), getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.DEVICE_IMEI)),
            getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.TRANSACTION_ID)));
        System.out.println("token in skitto: " + getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.RTR_TOKEN_ID)));
        System.out.println("imei in skitto: " + getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.DEVICE_IMEI)));;
        System.out.println("transaction in skitto: " + getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.TRANSACTION_ID)));
        System.out.println("POS in skitto: " + getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.POS_CODE)));
    }
}
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.POS_CODE)) != null) {
        RestApi restApi = new RestApi(this, context);
restApi.checkPOS(getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.RTR_TOKEN_ID)), getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.DEVICE_IMEI)),
                getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.TRANSACTION_ID)));
        System.out.println("token in skitto: " + getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.RTR_TOKEN_ID)));
        System.out.println("imei in skitto: " + getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.DEVICE_IMEI)));;
        System.out.println("transaction in skitto: " + getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.TRANSACTION_ID)));
        System.out.println("POS in skitto: " + getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.POS_CODE)));
    }
}
```

Then inside the onResponseLoaded function I used the runnable funcation to display the dialog as below:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    errorDialogue("Incorrect validation. Please try again"); <-- error here
                }
            });

public void errorDialogue(String message) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_failed_pos_login, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.failedMsg);
    descriptionTextView.setText(message);
    //Do your UI operations like dialog opening or Toast here
    errorApiAlertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    errorApiAlertDialog.show();  <-- error here

    final Button retryBtn = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btntryAgain);
    retryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            errorApiAlertDialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

After reading many other stackoverflow questions on this topic, I added onPause() and onStop() methods as following:

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (errorApiAlertDialog != null && errorApiAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
        errorApiAlertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (errorApiAlertDialog != null && errorApiAlertDialog.isShowing()) {
        errorApiAlertDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

My application is not crashing though. The application shows the alert dialog and when i press the try again button the app closes and the above error is shown. Tried many other possible ways to solve this issue. What am i doing wrong here that the activity has leaked window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the error after removing the following duplicate code from onCreate()

```
if (getIntent().getStringExtra(getString(R.string.POS_CODE)) != null) {
    RestApi restApi = new RestApi(this, context);
.......//rest code

}
```

As the code was same in both onResume and onCreate, I was getting Activity has leaked windows. Now after removing the code from onCreate everything is fine.

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. And, yes, you can check as correct your own answer, it's considered best practice here at S.O.